# MS SQL:Pivot Table order columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, pivot

I'm hoping some can help clarify what I should be doing. I'm essentially reading in a Table with dates and then Im trying to convert these dates into individual columns.

Unfortunately the columns come out out of order. How do I order these columns into |01/01/2013|02/01/2013| etc? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GL_Effective_Date) 
            FROM [03_rdm].[Table_2013] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Ref_Account_Class, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select TOP 100 PERCENT
                    Ref_Account_Class
                    , GL_Amount
                    , GL_Effective_Date
                from [03_rdm].[Table_2013]
                where Ref_Account_Class = ''Accounts Receivable''
                order by  GL_Effective_Date
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(GL_Amount)
                for GL_Effective_Date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
execute(@query)
```

Comment: i tried this but got the error-"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Comment: Yep, my bad. Forgot how strict DISTINCT was for a minute. You need to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order in this statement:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GL_Effective_Date) 
        FROM [03_rdm].[Table_2013] c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

When using distinct though, you can only order by items in the select list, so you can't order by `c.GL_Effective_Date`, it would need to be the full statement (`',' + QUOTENAME(c.GL_Effective_Date)`, but since `QUOTENAME` implicitly converts your date to a `VARCHAR` these will not come out in order. So instead of DISTINCT you can use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GL_Effective_Date) 
        FROM [03_rdm].[Table_2013] c
        GROUP BY c.GL_Effective_Date
        ORDER BY c.GL_Effective_Date
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Which should give the ordering you require. This should also be marginally more efficient, although probably not noticably. When you use a scalar function with distinct the function is applied to all rows, then duplicates removed from the results, however with group by, first duplicates are removed, then the function is applied to the results. As mentioned, this will not be noticable with `QUOTENAME`, but be a useful bit of knowledge to have for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `distinct`, use `group by`:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GL_Effective_Date) 
                   FROM [03_rdm].[Table_2013] c
                   GROUP BY c.GL_Effective_Date
                   ORDER BY c.GL_Effective_Date
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
                 1, 1, '');
```